# CAN Bus on 96Boards Hikey via MCP2515

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I am currently trying to get a CAN bus interface working upon the 96Boards Hikey development board through the use of an MCP2515, which I have connected via the SPI to the Lo-speed connector on the Hikey board.

It is of my understanding that to enable this, some slight modifications need to be made to the device tree files. I have not, however, been able to get the MCP2515 recognised as an SPI device, or the can0 interface to appear within Linux.

I am new to anything related to device trees, and so have made attempts at altering the approaches made within these two posts:

```
http://www.96boards.org/forums/topic/get-can-bus-working-on-db410c-via-mcp2515/
https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/371
```

Currently my device tree file looks like the following:

```
#include "hikey-gpio.dtsi"
/{
    aliases {
            spi_0    = &spi_0 ;
    };
    clocks{
            clk16m: oscillator {
                    #clock-cells = <0>;
                    compatible = "fixed-clock";
                    clock-frequency = <16000000>; //16MHz
            };
    };
    soc{
            spi_0: spi@f7106000 {
                    #address-cells = <1>;
                    #size-cells = <0>;
                    can0: mcp2515@0 {
                            compatible = "microchip,mcp2515";
                            reg = <0>;
                            clocks = <&clk16m>;
                            interrupt-parent = <&gpio2>;
                            interrupts = <0 0x2>;
                            spi-max-frequency = <10000000>; //10 MHz
                    };
            };
    };
};
```

I am not completely sure that I have setup the interrupt pin correctly. The interrupt pin I am using is pin 23 on the lo-speed connector, GPIO2_0.

If anyone with more experience could have a look and let me know what could be wrong with this code, it would be much appreciated!  If my question is too specific, let me know if there is anything that I can or should make clearer.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I’m able to see the device and send a message, but not receive. I think something might be wonky with the interrupt.